# Hashem's Name in Hashiva Shofteinu

Tags: minhag, prayer-book, nuschaot, nusach-ashkenaz, yekke

In the ברכה of השיבה שופטינו, all סידורים that I have seen (including really yekkish ones) have the words "אתה ה' לבדך", all סידורים that is, except the סידור הרוקח. The רוקח does not have Hashem's name there. Instead, the ברכה reads:

> הָשִׁיבָה שׁופְטֵינוּ כְּבָרִאשׁונָה וְיועֲצֵינוּ כְּבַתְּחִלָּה.
>   וְהָסֵר מִמֶּנּוּ יָגון וַאֲנָחָה. וּמְלךְ עָלֵינוּ **אַתָּה 
>   לְבַדְּךָ** בְּחֶסֶד וּבְרַחֲמִים. וְצַדְּקֵנוּ בַּמִשְׁפָּט. בָּרוּךְ
>   אַתָּה ה', מֶלֶךְ אוהֵב צְדָקָה וּמִשְׁפָּט

This fits in with what the רוקח says beforehand:

> השיבה שופטינו כ''ד תיבות

- The ברכה has 24 words. In our ברכה, there are 25 words.

So, my question is why do **all** סידורים nowadays have Hashem's name inserted there if the רוקח says the ברכה is supposed to have 24 words

Comment: Seemingly other people thought the blessing should have a different number of words...

Comment: Why do you think that they knew or cared about rokeahs count?

Comment: resource https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D7%A2%D6%B8%D7%9C%D6%B5%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D6%BC+%D7%90%D6%B7%D7%AA%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%94+%D7%9C%D6%B0%D7%91%D6%B7%D7%93%D6%BC%D6%B0%D7%9A%D6%B8%22&oq=%22%D7%A2%D6%B8%D7%9C%D6%B5%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D6%BC+%D7%90%D6%B7%D7%AA%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%94+%D7%9C%D6%B0%D7%91%D6%B7%D7%93%D6%BC%D6%B0%D7%9A%D6%B8%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...15275.18456.0.19161.2.2.0.0.0.0.135.258.0j2.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.134...33i160k1.0.GKWB1e0ORQ8

Comment: Emden clearly writes it (p. 261 on HebrewBooks), but I can't figure out the comment due to poor scan quality...

Comment: BL Machzor Vitry also contains it (f. 37)